# Jmeter - Creating a new variable if variable already exists using Java

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter and want to use Java to update variables,

I have a variable called XXVONO which stores values and adds a number suffix when executed in a loop. Example:

```
XXVONO_1 = value1

XXVONO_2 = value2

XXVONO_3 = value3
```

These variables contains values which are automatically stored when the loop is executed. However, I am trying to make a code which checks if the variable is empty or not, If true, it will save the new values, where if false, it will create a new variable (XXVONO_4) and save the value there without overwriting the existing variables.

How would I go about doing this? Do I use a while loop?

```
if (vars.get("VONO_2") != "") {
    if (vars.get("XXVONO_" + vars.get("aps200_count_3")) == "") {
        vars.put("XXVONO_" + vars.get("aps200_count_3"), vars.get("VONO_2"));
        vars.put("XXJRNO_" + vars.get("aps200_count_3"), vars.get("JRNO_2"));
    } else {
        while (vars.get("XXVONO_" + vars.get("aps200_count_3")) != "") {
            vars.put("new_count", vars.get("aps200_count_3"));
            Integer temp = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("new_count")) + 1;
            vars.put("new_count", temp.toString());         
        }
        vars.put("XXVONO_" + vars.get("new_count"), vars.get("VONO_2"));
        vars.put("XXJRNO_" + vars.get("new_count"), vars.get("JRNO_2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: why jmeter tag?

Comment: I am using this in JMeter

Comment: can we see the code? mostly how you are creating the variables.

Comment: vars.put("XXVONO_" + vars.get("tmp_cnt"), vars.get("VONO_2"));

Comment: Apologies to those that have posted answers to help without me being too clear. I was unfamiliar with the formatting and was unable to post the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a map instead of creating a variables at runtime

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Inside the loop

```
if(map.get("DynamicVariableName")!=null){
    map.put("DynamicVariableName"+autogeneratedNumberSuffix,ValueToBeStored)
}
else{
map.put("DynamicVariableName",ValueToBeStored)
}
```

Comment: I've just added the code that I use for JMeter. Will the solution you've added here work on JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use an if/else statement:

```
if (XXVONO_1 == null)
{
  XXYVONO_1 = //Insert data here
}
else if (XXVONO_2 == null)
{
  XXVONO_2 = //Insert data here
}
else  if (XXVONO_3 == null)
{
  XXVONO_3 == //Insert data here
}
else
{
  XXVONO_4 == //Insert data here
}
```

Of course, you can keep adding variables.

If there is no limit to the number of variables, try this:

```
HashMap<String, String> XXVONO = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (i = 1; i <= /*Number of variables*/; i += 1; i++) {
  if (XXVONO["XXVONO_" + i] == null) {
    XXVONO.put("XXVONO_" + i, /*insert data here*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd want to code it just so, so that it would automatically add a new number suffix everytime I execute my script and store the value found in VONO_2/JRNO_2

Comment: Is there a limit to how many variables there should be? If not, I suggest using an array/hash.

Comment: I added to the answer.